# yaccの作り方

Tags: python, c

こんにちは。
私はyaccの作り方に興味があるのですが、日本語の解説のあるlalr(1)パーサージェネレーターのソースコードを探しています。
どなたか、日本語の解説のあるlalr(1)パーサージェネレーターをご存じないでしょうか。
言語はC言語かpythonを希望します。
私の話を聞いていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: LALRの仕組み自体はご存じで実装方法を知りたいという状況でしょうか、それともLALRの仕組みから知りたいという状況でしょうか？

Comment: レスありがとうございます。ドラゴンブックは持っています。大体のLALR(1)の仕組みは知っているのですが、プログラムにできません。つまり、実際の実装をわかりやすく知りたいという状況です。

Answer (score 1):

C++ で良ければ、caper というパーサージェネレーターの[ソースコード](https://github.com/jonigata/caper)についているコメントが日本語であるのを見つけました。

「C か Python で実装されていて」「全体にコメントがついていて」「コメントが日本語である」ような実装は簡単に調べただけだと見つからなかったので、教科書の記述から実際のソースコードに落とすやり方が分からなかった部分を個別に小さく区切って新しい質問として投稿頂く方が効率的かもしれません。